# ruamel.yaml edit document before dump

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file which has documents of this sort

```
%YAML 1.2
---
!some_tag
name: xyz
constants:
  state: abc
```

After reading in the documents, before dumping using ruamel.yaml.YAML().dump, I want to remove this part of the document

```
%YAML 1.2
---
```

My output file should have just these sections of the document

```
!some_tag
name: xyz
constants:
  state: abc
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an explicit tag with version the `.version` attribute on the
`YAML()` instance gets set. You can either instantiate a new instance for dumping
or just set that attribute to `None`:

```
import sys
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml

inp = pathlib.Path('input.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(inp)
print(f'>>> version info {yaml.version}\n')
yaml.version = None
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
>>> version info (1, 2)

!some_tag
name: xyz
constants:
  state: abc
```